# k8s securityContext.runAsUser vs Dockerfile USER instruction

Tags: docker, kubernetes

What is the difference between selecting the user to run as in the `securityContext.runAsUser` section of my k8s deployment, vs specifying the user using `USER myuser` in the Dockerfile?

I'm particularly interested in if there are security concerns associated with `USER myuser` that don't exist under `securityContext`

Comment: Hi Mike S, did you got any satisfying answer to this question?

Answer (score 2):

#### MustRunAsNonRoot

[Users and groups](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#users-and-groups)

> Requires that the pod be submitted with a `non-zero runAsUser` or have the `USER directive defined` (using a numeric UID) in the image.
>   Pods which have specified neither runAsNonRoot nor runAsUser settings
>   will be mutated to set `runAsNonRoot=true`, thus requiring a defined
>   `non-zero numeric USER directive` in the container. No default
>   provided. Setting allowPrivilegeEscalation=false is strongly
>   recommended with this strategy.

So `USER directive` is important when you want the container to be started as non-root.

Comment: @Mike S Does it answer your question ?